# NetworkTransport : Send multiple data to server and clients

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, networking, split

I went through an extensive tutorial on how to implement Unity's NetworkTransport and it was all making sense while I was following along but once I finished and I started to make changes, everything went sideways for me. I need a bit of help to understand how everything relates between the server and client scripts and how to add additional variables to send to the server/clients.

From where the scripts are currently, I'm adding two additional variables (a Texture2D and a string) on the client side that get added to my player class and passed to the server and the other clients.

I've started in the client script by adding these two additional variables to my Player class and also adding the same variables to my ServerClient class on the server script. Then in the client script in the SpawnPlayer function I pass those two additional variables but I'm getting confused with how I initially create the proper string to hold these two new variables. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be incredibly helpful. Thank you!

'NetworkServerController.cs'

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Text;

public class ServerClient
{
    public int connectionID;
    public string playerName;
    public Texture2D animalTex;
    public string animalType;
    public Vector3 position;
}

public class NetworkServerController : MonoBehaviour {

    private const int MAX_CONNECTION = 10;
    private int port = 5701;

    private int hostID;
    private int webHostID;

    private string networkConnections;

    private int reliableChannel;
    private int unreliableChannel;
    private int reliableFragChannel;
    private int unreliableFragChannel;

    private bool isStarted = false;
    private byte error;

    private List<ServerClient> clients = new List<ServerClient>();

    private float lastMovementUpdate;
    private float movementUpdateRate = 0.2f;

    // Onscreen Variables
    private string connectText;
    private string dataText;
    private string clientID;

    private void Awake()
    {
        NetworkServer.Reset();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        NetworkTransport.Init();
        ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();

        reliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
        unreliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);
        reliableFragChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableFragmented);
        unreliableFragChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.UnreliableFragmented);

        HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(cc, MAX_CONNECTION);

        hostID = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, port);
        Debug.Log("Socket Open. HostID is : " + hostID);

        webHostID = NetworkTransport.AddWebsocketHost(topo, port);
        Debug.Log("Socket Open. webHostID is : " + webHostID);

        isStarted = true;
    }

    int connectionId;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!isStarted)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (isStarted)
        {
            // Debug.Log("Server Started.");

            int recHostId;
            int channelId;
            byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferSize = 1024;
            int dataSize;
            byte error;
            NetworkEventType recData = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostId, out connectionId, out channelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);

            // Network Messenger System
            switch (recData)
            {
                case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:    //2
                    Debug.Log("Player " + connectionId + "has connected.");
                    OnConnection(connectionId);
                    break;

                case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:       //3
                    string msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(recBuffer, 0, dataSize);
                    Debug.Log("Receiving from " + connectionId + " : " + msg);
                    string[] splitData = msg.Split('|');

                    switch (splitData[0])
                    {
                        case "NAMEIS":
                            OnNameIs(connectionId, splitData[1]);
                            break;

                        case "MYPOSITION":
                            OnMyPosition(connectionId, float.Parse(splitData[1]), float.Parse(splitData[2]));
                            break;

                        default:
                            Debug.Log("Invalid message : " + msg);
                            break;
                    }

                    break;

                case NetworkEventType.DisconnectEvent: //4
                    Debug.Log("Player " + connectionId + "has disconnected.");
                    OnDisconnection(connectionId);
                    break;
            }

            // Ask player for their position
            if (Time.time - lastMovementUpdate > movementUpdateRate)
            {
                lastMovementUpdate = Time.time;
                string m = "ASKPOSITION|";
                foreach (ServerClient sc in clients)
                    m += sc.connectionID.ToString() + '%' + sc.position.x.ToString() + '%' + sc.position.y.ToString() + '|';
                m = m.Trim('|');

                Send(m, unreliableChannel, clients);
            }
        }       
    }

    private void OnConnection(int cnnID)
    {
        // Add player to list
        ServerClient c = new ServerClient();
        c.connectionID = cnnID;
        c.playerName = "TEMP";
        clients.Add(c);

        // When player joins server, tell ID
        // Request player name and send name of all the other players
        string msg = "ASKNAME|" + cnnID + "|";
        foreach (ServerClient sc in clients)
            msg += sc.playerName + '%' + sc.connectionID + "|";

        msg = msg.Trim('|');

        // ASKNAME|3|DAVE%1|MIKE%2|TEMP%3

        Send(msg, reliableChannel, cnnID);
    }

    private void OnDisconnection(int cnnId)
    {
        // Remove this player from our client list
        clients.Remove(clients.Find(x => x.connectionID == cnnId));

        // Tell everyone that someone has disconnected
        Send("DC|" + cnnId, reliableChannel, clients);
    }

    private void OnNameIs(int cnnID, string playerName)
    {
        // Link name to connection ID
        clients.Find(x => x.connectionID == cnnID).playerName = playerName;

        // Tell everone that a new player has connected
        Send("CNN|" + playerName + '|' + cnnID, reliableChannel, clients);
    }

    private void OnMyPosition(int cnnId, float x, float y)
    {
        clients.Find(c => c.connectionID == cnnId).position = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
    }

    private void Send(string message, int channelID, int cnnID)
    {
        List<ServerClient> c = new List<ServerClient>();
        c.Add(clients.Find(x => x.connectionID == cnnID));
        Send(message, channelID, c);
    }

    // overload method
    private void Send(string message, int channelID, List<ServerClient> c)
    {
        Debug.Log("Sending : " + message);
        byte[] msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
        foreach(ServerClient sc in c)
        {
            NetworkTransport.Send(hostID, sc.connectionID, channelID, msg, message.Length * sizeof(char), out error);
        }
    }
}
```

'NetworkClientController'.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Text;

public class Player
{
    public string playerName;
    public GameObject avatar;
    public int connectionId;
    public Texture2D animalTex;
    public string animalType;
}

public class NetworkClientController : MonoBehaviour {

    private const int MAX_CONNECTION = 10;
    private int port = 5701;
    private string IPAddress = "192.168.1.160";

    private int hostID;
    private int webHostID;

    private int reliableChannel;
    private int unreliableChannel;
    private int reliableFragChannel;
    private int unreliableFragChannel;

    private int ourClientID;
    private int connectionID;

    private float connectionTime;
    private bool isConnected = false;
    private bool isStarted = false;
    private byte error;

    private string playerName;

    public GameObject playerPrefab;
    public Dictionary<int, Player> players = new Dictionary<int, Player>();

    private void Start()
    {
        // Connect();
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        // Check player name
        string pName = GameObject.Find("NameInput").GetComponent<InputField>().text;

        if (pName == "")
        {
            Debug.Log("You must enter a name");
            return;
        }

        playerName = pName;

        NetworkTransport.Init();
        ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();

        reliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
        unreliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);
        reliableFragChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableFragmented);
        unreliableFragChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.UnreliableFragmented);

        HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(cc, MAX_CONNECTION);

        hostID = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, port);
        connectionID = NetworkTransport.Connect(hostID, IPAddress, port, 0, out error);

        connectionTime = Time.time;
        isConnected = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!isConnected)
            return;

        int recHostId;
        int connectionId;
        int channelId;
        byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        int dataSize;
        byte error;
        NetworkEventType recData = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostId, out connectionId, out channelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);

        // Network Messenger System
        switch (recData)
        {
            case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:       //3
                string msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(recBuffer, 0, dataSize);
                Debug.Log("Receiving " + msg);
                string[] splitData = msg.Split('|');

                switch (splitData[0])
                {
                    case "ASKNAME":
                        OnAskName(splitData);
                        break;

                    case "ASKPOSITION":
                        OnAskPosition(splitData);
                        break;

                    case "CNN":
                        SpawnPlayer(splitData[1], int.Parse(splitData[2]));
                        break;

                    case "DC":
                        PlayerDisconnected(int.Parse(splitData[1]));
                        break;

                    default:
                        Debug.Log("Invalid message : " + msg);
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OnAskName(string[] data)
    {
        // Set local client ID
        ourClientID = int.Parse(data[1]);

        // Send local client name to the server
        Send("NAMEIS|" + playerName, reliableChannel);

        // Create all remote client players
        for(int i = 2; i < data.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            string[] d = data[i].Split('%');
            SpawnPlayer(d[0], int.Parse(d[1]));
        }
    }

    private void OnAskPosition(string[] data)
    {
        if (!isStarted)
            return;

        // Update remote client positions
        for (int i = 1; i < data.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            string[] d = data[i].Split('%');

            // Prevent the server from updating local client
            if (ourClientID != int.Parse(d[0]))
            {
                Vector3 position = Vector3.zero;
                position.x = float.Parse(d[1]);
                position.y = float.Parse(d[2]);
                players[int.Parse(d[0])].avatar.transform.position = position;
            }
        }

        // Send local client position
        Vector3 myPosition = players[ourClientID].avatar.transform.position;
        string m = "MYPOSITION" + myPosition.x.ToString() + '|' + myPosition.y.ToString();
        Send(m, unreliableChannel);
    }

    private void SpawnPlayer(string playerName, int cnnId, Texture2D animalTex, string animalType)
    {
        GameObject go = Instantiate(playerPrefab) as GameObject;

        // Is this ours?
        if (cnnId == ourClientID)
        {
            // Add mobility
            go.AddComponent<PlayerMovement>();

            // Remove Canvas
            GameObject.Find("Canvas").SetActive(false);
            isStarted = true;
        }

        Player p = new Player();
        p.avatar = go;
        p.playerName = playerName;
        p.connectionId = cnnId;
        p.avatar.GetComponentInChildren<TextMesh>().text = playerName;
        p.animalTex = animalTex;
        p.animalType = animalType;
        players.Add(cnnId, p);
    }

    private void PlayerDisconnected(int cnnId)
    {
        Destroy(players[cnnId].avatar);
        players.Remove(cnnId);
    }

    private void Send(string message, int channelID)
    {
        Debug.Log("Sending : " + message);
        byte[] msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
        NetworkTransport.Send(hostID, connectionID, channelID, msg, message.Length * sizeof(char), out error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, could you provide a link to said tutorial?

Comment: Hi @Fiffe the link to the tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGkkaNkq8co

Comment: thank you @greyBow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply this, serialize and send the data then receive and de-serialize it. If you are still confused then read the steps below:

In your example, you want to send `Texture2D` and a `string`:

**SENDING SIDE:**

**1**.First step is to represent the data to send in a class or structure.

You don't want to directly add `Texture2D` to this class. You need to store it as byte array. This example uses `Texture2D.GetRawTextureData()` to do that. You can also convert it to PNG or JPEG byte array to decrease the size.

```
[Serializable]
public class SendStructure
{
    public byte[] texture;
    public string message;

    public SendStructure(Texture2D texture, string message)
    {
        this.texture = texture.GetRawTextureData();
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

**2**.Serialize data to send:

Example of data to send:

```
Texture2D textureToSend = new Texture2D(4, 4);
string stringToSend = "Hello";
```

Create new instance of of the sturcture from the Texture2D and string:

```
SendStructure sendStructure = new SendStructure(textureToSend, stringToSend);
```

Serialize into memory

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(memStream, sendStructure);

//Array data to send over network
byte[] serializedStructure = memStream.ToArray();
```

**3**.Send to network

```
NetworkTransport.Send(hostID, sc.connectionID, channelID, serializedStructure, serializedStructure.Length, out error);
```

---

**RECEIVING SIDE:**

**4**.Receive from network

```
int outHostId;
int outConnectionId;
int outChannelId;

int receivedSize;
byte error;

//Where to store received data
byte[] buffer = new byte[400000];

NetworkEventType evt = NetworkTransport.Receive(out outHostId, out outConnectionId, out outChannelId, buffer, buffer.Length, out receivedSize, out error);
```

**5**.De-serialize received data:

```
switch (evt)
{
    case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:
        {
            //De-Serialize recevied byte array into memory
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, receivedSize);
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            //Received data now stored as SendStructure
            SendStructure receivedStructure = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as SendStructure;

            break;
        }
}
```

**6**.Access received data:

Retrieve the `string`:

```
string receivedString = receivedStructure.message;
```

Retrieve the `Texture2D`:

```
Texture2D receivedtexture = new Texture2D(4, 4);
receivedtexture.LoadRawTextureData(receivedStructure.texture);
receivedtexture.Apply();
```